# MySQL: define the right indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have this table:

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| CODE                | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| REVISION            | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| NAME                | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

now, my app will perform these queries (from more likely to less likely):

1. `SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE ID = ?`
2. `SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE CODE = ? ORDER BY REVISION DESC`
3. `SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE CODE = ? AND REVISION = ?`
4. `SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE CODE LIKE ? OR NAME LIKE ? ORDER BY CODE ASC, REVISION DESC`

What is the best combination of indexes for such a scenario?

I'm using MySQL 5.6.14 (InnoDB) on Windows 8.1 x64.

---

**UPDATE** (still testing):

The best so far is using separate indexes: IDX_CODE (CODE), IDX_NAME (NAME).

```
mysql> describe select id, code, revision from UNIT where code like 'M0170SIGM1%' or name like 'M0170SIGM1%' ORDER BY code ASC, revision DESC;
+----+-------------+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type        | possible_keys     | key               | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                            |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | UNIT  | index_merge | IDX_CODE,IDX_NAME | IDX_CODE,IDX_NAME | 767,767 | NULL |   31 | Using sort_union(IDX_CODE,IDX_NAME); Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

No way to make MySQL use indexes in double direction sorting.

Comment: and what is you engine innodb, myisam, archive or some other thing

Comment: InnoDB, sorry I forgot to mention

Comment: Does your app perform inserts? And could a wildcard occur at the beginning of a LIKE query?

Comment: yes meanly 1 insert on ~200 queries and yes, but is is unlikely

Answer (score 1):

The primary key takes care of the first query.

For the second and third:  `item(code, revision)`.  Note that the `order by case asc` is unnecessary because you are only choosing one code.

The last query is problematic.  You might want to use a full text index.  If the `like` attern is does not have a wild card at the beginning, then the following formulation might be better:

```
select i.*
from (select i.* from item i where code like ? union
      select i.* from item i where name like ?
     ) i
order by code, revision;
```

However, the engine is probably going to implement this query using full-table scan followed by a sort, regardless of the indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I corrected queries 2 and 3. The `like` attern will likely be `somevalue%`, but I'm using JPA and I don't know yet how to make it declare fulltext indexes in DDL auto generation. Would `item(code, revision, name)` be of some help in the 4th query?

Comment: @MicheleMariotti . . . It is possible that a SQL engine could use the index for the `order by` and then do the comparison row-by-row.  I don't think that MySQL will do that, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

For your fourth case with the mixed asc/desc order it might fail completely to use an index since mysql seems not to support this combination:

[Order-By-Optimization in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html)

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY,
>   although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the WHERE
>   clause. These cases include the following:
>
> ```
> ...
>
> You mix ASC and DESC:
>
> SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 ASC;
> ```

**Possible solution for that problem:**

if your revision would be simply an positive integer, you could use another column with that value multiplied by -1, and order by this column DESC, which would allow you to use an index on those two columns, since they would have the same direction... works here like a charm with a timestamp column...

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it's not a number.